# How to perform a mysql join query to get matching values b/w 2 tables and then filter values that not exists in third table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables `applicants`,`claims`,`clearances`. `applicants` and `claims` have one-to-many mapping. `claims` and `clearances` have one-to-one mapping. So `applicants` and `clearances` have one-to-many mapping.

`applicants.id` is mapped to `claims.applicant_id`. Both `applicants.id` and `claims.id` are mapped to `clearances.applicant_id` and `clearances.claim_id`.

I'm trying to perform joins b/w these 3 tables where I want to fetch all *claims* related to an *applicant* but want to filter out those *claims* which are already present in *clearances*. So that I can fetch only *uncleared claims* belonging to an *applicant*.

I could use this result set to return list of *uncleared claims* for an endpoint and also when this result set returns 0 rows (meaning all *claims* of an *applicant* in `claims` table are also present in `clearance` table), I need to update a column for that *applicant* in `applicants` table.

I tried something like:

```
Select claims.id from claims 
   inner join applicants on applicants.id = claims.applicant_id inner join 
   clearances on (clearances.applicant_id != applicants.id AND 
   clearances.claim_id != claims.id) where applicants.id = ?;
```

But this is not outputting desired result. I've tried with NOT EXISTS but I'm unable to construct syntactically correct query with it.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: provide some sample data and your desired output in table format

Comment: *Both applicants.id and claims.id are mapped to clearances.applicant_id and clearances.claim_id.* This is wrong. It is possible that the same clearance refers to different applicants directly and via claim.

Comment: @Akina I understand that. The entire design is bad. But we cannot change anything in the schema provided by client. Hence the struggle.

Comment: You must decide. Either you claims one of this relation chains as minor (what?) and use only main relation chain or you use both and are ready to empty output when some integrity problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT claims.id 
FROM claims 
INNER JOIN applicants ON applicants.id = claims.applicant_id 
LEFT JOIN clearances ON clearances.applicant_id = applicants.id 
                    AND clearances.claim_id = claims.id 
WHERE clearances.id IS NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT claims.id 
FROM claims 
INNER JOIN applicants ON applicants.id = claims.applicant_id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM clearances 
                   WHERE clearances.applicant_id = applicants.id 
                     AND clearances.claim_id = claims.id );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So the trick is to find that clearance row that does not exists where it has given applicant_id & claim_id right? Is that why we're passing clearances.id = null or did I understood it wrong. Could use a bit of explanation :)

Also, in case I wanna have the schema slightly tweaked (need to persuade my team) for better design, can maintaining an additional column in "claims" table that represent it's clearance status would be a better option? That way we can filter uncleared claims from claims table itself isn't it?

Thank you for your help again :)

Comment: *So the trick is to find that clearance row that does not exists where it has given applicant_id & claim_id right?* Absolutely correct. The equivalent which uses NOT EXISTS added (and it can be even faster). *can maintaining an additional column in "claims" table that represent it's clearance status be a better option?* You have over-defined data already - and you want to aggravate the situation? that's your choice... Moreover, I'd think about to remove `clearances` at all and move the columns specific for clearance process into `applicants` - I'm not afraid of sparse tables personally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply again!! :)